# Jenkins Active Directory integration

Tags: jenkins, jboss, active-directory, connectexception

I am trying to integrate Active directory for logging on Jenkins and facing a strange issue. I have a local setup of Jenkins on Tomcat on Windows and able to achieve Active Directory integration using [Active Directory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+Plugin). But when I put the same thing over my production jenkins running on JBOSS and RHEL I am facing the below exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:363)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203)
Caused: javax.naming.CommunicationException: XXXXXXXXXXXX [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:137)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1614)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2746)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:151)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:660)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:645)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:592)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:557)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.bind(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:626)
at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryDomain$DescriptorImpl.doValidateTest(ActiveDirectoryDomain.java:305)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:734)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:864)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:92)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:656)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But I am able to telnet to the IP via my server. Please advise.

Comment: It's a timeout issue meaning some connection problem is there. Something which you are using is not letting successfully connect to the server you are trying to

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out the issue. The linux user was a system account. Thus active directory was not authenticating the request